# if we declare an event in HTML tag, what is it called?

Tags: javascript, html

Example:

```
<input type="text" oninput="Update(this.value,'name')">
```

my question is, what is this (oninput event) thing called?

like **inline javascript**?
or **html event**?

or something else?

are we accessing **javascript event from html**?

Becuase we have to define **Update() in the script**.

Comment: [DOM onevent handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're called [event handler content attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-content-attributes) in the HTML specification:

> Event handlers are exposed in two ways.
>
> [...]
>
> The second way is as an event handler content attribute. Event
> handlers on HTML elements and some of the event handlers on `Window`
> objects are exposed in this way.
>
> For both of these two ways, the event handler is exposed through a
> **name**, which is a string that always starts with "`on`" and is followed
> by the name of the event for which the handler is intended.